# Compiled find in VC++ but G++ giving 'undefined reference' problems when linking.

Tags: c++, class

To compile in Linux, I just run 'g++ driver.cpp' but I am getting a lot of problems when linking.

```
/tmp/ccABk939.o: In function `createCharacter()':
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `Character::Character(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Class*, int)'
/tmp/ccABk939.o: In function `save(Character*)':
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x1c2): undefined reference to `Character::getName()'
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x2e1): undefined reference to `Character::printSave()'
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `Character::getClass()'
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x37a): undefined reference to `Class::printSave()'
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x3ff): undefined reference to `Character::getWeapon()'
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x417): undefined reference to `Character::getWeapon()'
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x42b): undefined reference to `Weapon::printSave()'
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x4ce): undefined reference to `Character::getArmor()'
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x4e6): undefined reference to `Character::getArmor()'
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x4fa): undefined reference to `Armor::printSave()'
Driver.cpp:(.text+0x59d): undefined reference to `Character::getShield()'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What has `find` got to do with anything? Are you trying to search for dependencies?

Comment: I think he meant... Compiled fine :)

Answer (score 4):

If **Character** methods are defined in Character.cpp do.

```
   g++ driver.cpp Character.cpp
```

Add as many *.cpp to g++ as you have. Maybe **Class.cpp Armor.cpp** etc etc

If it is defined in a library you have to [use link options to link against it](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Comment: This is precisely why I encourage beginners not to use an IDE.

Answer (score 1):

```
g++ x.cpp y.cpp
```

compiles and then links necessary objects and results in an executable file.

```
g++ -c x.cpp y.cpp
```

only compiles, doesn't link files, so doesn't create an executable.

```
g++ x.cpp y.cpp -lmath
```

the -l links libraries if you need linkage.

Besides all; if you are using Linux, you must consider writing a MAKEFILE. It solves your problem once and for all.